# "Xcode helper" would like to control this computer. Is this request legit?

Tags: security, xcode

[image]

I haven't seen this request in earlier version of xcode. Why does XCode Helper require this permission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using UI testing on macOS, then yes, this is legit:

> macOS needs permissions granted to a special Xcode Helper app. You are prompted for this automatically on your first use of UI tests.

(see [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html)).

This is needed because UI testing uses the accessibility features of macOS to drive your UI during the test runs.

Comment: I'm bemused by the fact that in our app submissions, the plist strings have to supply a reason _why_ the permission is being requested (and I've had apps temporarily rejected for plist entries that weren't sufficiently descriptive), but then Apple's own apps don't explain why they need this permission (or the permissions dialog isn't showing it).